# How to read and write on Netty channelRead()

Tags: java, sockets, netty

Im running Netty and i need to read some messages from the client.
Then i need to execute some actions in the Server, then send a response to the client.
Maybe the Client need to answer again to the server.
I think all this have to happend in the same Thread.
How can i do this in the Netty server?
Im testing the code below using Telnet but i cant get a response from the server.
If i Comment the first block, (Read message block), so i start to receive the response in the Telnet console.

```
@Override
public void channelRead(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, Object msg) { // (2)

    // Read the message sent from client.
    try{
        ByteBuf in = (ByteBuf) msg;
        try {
            while (in.isReadable()) { // (1)
                System.out.print((char) in.readByte());
                System.out.flush();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("---------------- Reading Exception ----------------");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            //ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg);
        }

        // treat the received message
        if(msg.equals("teste")){
            // do Something...
        }           

        //Answer to the client
        try {
            ctx.write(msg); // (1)
            ctx.flush(); // (2) 
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("---------------- Writing Exception ----------------");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    finally {
        //ReferenceCountUtil.release(msg); // (2)
    }       

}
```

Answer (score 0):

after the while loop: `while (in.isReadable()) {...}`, the msg ByteBuf is not readable anymore, so nothing will be written to the client via `ctx.write(msg)`